# Strange Skipping Listener Behaviour in Read and Write Operations

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a job that reads a flat file of 11 records. I skip 1 item in reader and 4 in writers. I have one `Skiplistener` with `SkipInRead()` and `SkipInWrite()` method which simple logs the skip message in DB. Why my `onSkipInRead` is being called multiple times i.e. 3 times in this case which in result logs same message in DB 3 times. `OnSkipinWrite` works fine

```
<job id="ex_Job">
    <step id="load">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" commit-interval="3" skip-limit="10">
                <skippable-exception-classes>
                    <include class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException" />
                    <include class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.IncorrectLineLengthException" />
                    <include class="org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException"/>
                </skippable-exception-classes>
            </chunk>
            <listeners>
                <listener ref="genericSkipListener" />
            </listeners>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>
```

---

```
public class GenericSkipListener extends AbstractBaseSkipListener implements
    SkipListener<FieldSet, FieldSet> {

private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(GenericSkipListener.class);

@Autowired
private SkipedItemsDao skipedItemsDao;


@Override
public void onSkipInRead(final Throwable t) {
    LOGGER.warn("[" + getJobName() + "] onSkipInRead:" + t);
    skipedItemsDao.saveReadSkippedItem(createReadSkipedItem("READ", "", t));
}

@Override
public void onSkipInWrite(final FieldSet item, final Throwable t) {
    LOGGER.warn("[" + getJobName() + "] onSkipWrite:" + t);
    skipedItemsDao.save(createSkipedItem("WRITE", item.toString(), t));
}

@Override
public void onSkipInProcess(final FieldSet item, final Throwable t) {
    LOGGER.warn("[" + getJobName() + "] onSkipInProcess:" + t);
    skipedItemsDao.save(createSkipedItem("PROCESS", item.toString(), t));
}
}
```

My `onSkipInRead()` method is being call multiple times for the same item. Any idea guys ?

Answer (score 0):

- *I skip 1 item in reader*

By doing what?

- *multiple times for the same item*

This would only be possible if you rereading the same item yourself, or you indeed have a single bad item repeated in your file 3 times.

- *3 times in this case*

`onSkipInRead` is called after commit interval is read (it respects transaction boundaries), so you may have a single item that "you skip" *per* commit interval. And if it is e.g. every 3rd item:

```
11 % 3 = 3 bad items skipped
```

#### EDIT after issue clarification (in comments)

In order to skip first X lines in the file, set `linesToSkip` on a `FlatFileItemReader`:

```
/** 
 *  Public setter for the number of lines to skip at the start of a file. 
 *  Can be used if the file contains a header without useful (column name) information, 
 *  and without a comment delimiter at the beginning of the lines.
 *
 *  linesToSkip - the number of lines to skip
 **/
public void setLinesToSkip( int linesToSkip ) { // ... }
```

Or/And, if there is anything special needs to be done for the first skipped lines:

```
/**
 * skippedLinesCallback - will be called for each one of the initial skipped lines 
 * before any items are read. 
 **/
public void setSkippedLinesCallback( LineCallbackHandler skippedLinesCallback ) { // ... }
```

Comment: No. There is only 1 item skipped in read process. This is the 1st line in the file while is skipped due to FileParseException as it contains shorter lenght data compared to rest of file.
So first 3 lines are read(commit-interval=3) and one line is skipped due to ParseException. The remaining 2 items are passed to Writer which are skipped due to DAOException(I am raising this by using duplicate key in read records).
What happening is that somehow my onSkipInRead is being called multiple time and read skipp item is being logged in DB multiple times